# common.inc error in newly downloaded Drupal 7.69

Tags: 7

I just downloaded drupal 7.69 and tried to configure it.  It gives me a page full of the same error:

> Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type int in element_children() (line 6656 of /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/KSnew/includes/common.inc).

Here's the relevant part of the code in common.inc, with line numbers:

```
6648 function element_children(&$elements, $sort = FALSE) {
6649   // Do not attempt to sort elements which have already been sorted.
6650   $sort = isset($elements['#sorted']) ? !$elements['#sorted'] : $sort;
6651 
6652   // Filter out properties from the element, leaving only children.
6653   $children = array();
6654   $sortable = FALSE;
6655   foreach ($elements as $key => $value) {
6656     if ($key === '' || $key[0] !== '#') {
6657       $children[$key] = $value;
6658       if (is_array($value) && isset($value['#weight'])) {
6659         $sortable = TRUE;
6660       }
6661     }
6662   }
```

Is this a Drupal error??

Comment: Wouldn't recommend starting a new project with D7 unless it's fairly short-lived https://www.drupal.org/psa-2019-02-25

Answer (score 2):

I think it is PHP related.  According to the [Drupal 7 php requirements](https://www.drupal.org/docs/7/system-requirements/php-requirements) PHP 7.4 is not fully supported.  If you are running on 7.4 perhaps try downgrading it to 7.3 and see if it makes a difference.

This is probably the [relevant issue](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupal/issues/3084935) that you encountered.  Alternatively see if you can use the latest patch in there and post your findings so you can help move the issue forward.

Comment: You are absolutely right! My former installation of MAMP was using PHP 7.3.8 and I did not have this problem.